# How to directly go in the recent activity once the User use other application and go back in android

Tags: java, android

Here is the scenario.

User --> Login Activity --> then once its password and username is true or valid. Go in the dashboard using startActivity(Intent(this,new.class)) with finish() method.

Current Activity
User --> Dashboard

When the user pressed back button it will be direct in the home page or outside of the application.

Then when I click the application again it will start the app like

Splash Screen --> Welcome Activity --> Login.

The question is. How can I let the user be directed to the dashboard after the user logs in and goes out of the application?

Like other apps maybe(facebook) after you login an press back button it will out in the application but when the user clicks it. The user will be directed in the Dashboard or home.

Comment: You will have to store the users login details when they login successfully, when they open the app again, on your splash screen (before moving to the login screen) fetch those details and check them and then move them to the dashboard instead of the login screen. This can be done using Room database, or you can use Shared Preferences: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences

Since you are a beginner I suggest using Share Preferences and then learn SQL Room

Comment: Thank you. I already get it but I will learn also from your suggestion. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I get the answer from the youtube guys.

Since I've used Firebase

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    if(mAuth.getCurrentUser() !=null){
        startActivity(new Intent(this, dashboard.class));
        this.finish();
    }
}
```

It simply check if the user already logged in and if its true it will be directed to the dashboard and skipped Login Activity.